# Magento2 : Create Dynamic URL by controller

Tags: magento2, url, products, review, router

I need the url structure like this :

From this url :- http://localhost/magento27/review/product/view/id/936/

To this url :-  http://localhost/magento27/women/review/love-this-product/936

```
women :- Category-Name
love-this-product :- Title of the Review
936 :- Id of review
```

How to create this dynamic url with controller?

Please help me.

Thanks.

Comment: For this case, you need create custom route

Comment: Any reference to create the custom route which works for this.

Comment: If still needed... This blog post may have the solution: http://alanstorm.com/magento_2_advanced_routing/

Comment: you can refer this link **https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/196957/magento-2-create-a-page-with-dynamic-url-with-same-controller**