# Magento 2: Create a Page with Dynamic URL with Same Controller

Tags: magento2, url, dynamic

I posted a question earlier but didn't able to understand the answer,

Magento 2: How to create a dynamic url with the same controller

i want to create a page with the dynamic url but with same controller to handle the requests,

for example: `http://192.168.1.108/magento2/profile/id/jatin123` and `http://192.168.1.108/magento2/profile/id/amit123`

just able to get the id and display the results accoring to the id = "jatin123" display this user profile and id="amit123" display this user profile.

Please suggest a solution.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can create it by with the help of `Magento\Framework\App\RouterList`. For this you need to create `di.xml` in your module (I am assuming that you know how to create module in M2). First create `di.xml` in below path,

`app/code/yourvendor/yourmodule/etc/frontend/di.xml`

In this file add

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\Framework\App\RouterList">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="routerList" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="cms" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="class" xsi:type="string">YOURVENDOR\YOURMODULE\Controller\Router</item>
                    <item name="disable" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                    <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="string">60</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </arguments>
    </type>
</config>
```

Now create a `YOURVENDOR\YOURMODULE\Controller\Router` but make sure  that It should `Implements` `\Magento\Framework\App\RouterInterface`

```
    namespace YOURVENDOR\YOURMODULE\Controller;

    class Router implements \Magento\Framework\App\RouterInterface
    {

     /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\App\ActionFactory
     */
    protected $actionFactory;

    /**
     * Event manager
     *
     * @var \Magento\Framework\Event\ManagerInterface
     */
    protected $_eventManager;

    /**
     * Store manager
     *
     * @var \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface
     */
    protected $_storeManager;


    /**
     * Config primary
     *
     * @var \Magento\Framework\App\State
     */
    protected $_appState;

    /**
     * Url
     *
     * @var \Magento\Framework\UrlInterface
     */
    protected $_url;

    /**
     * Response
     *
     * @var \Magento\Framework\App\ResponseInterface
     */
    protected $_response;


  public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\App\ActionFactory $actionFactory,
        \Magento\Framework\Event\ManagerInterface $eventManager,
        \Magento\Framework\UrlInterface $url,        
        \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager,
        \Magento\Framework\App\ResponseInterface $response
    ) {
        $this->actionFactory = $actionFactory;
        $this->_eventManager = $eventManager;
        $this->_url = $url;        
        $this->_storeManager = $storeManager;
        $this->_response = $response;
    }

     public function match(\Magento\Framework\App\RequestInterface $request)
       {
        $identifier = trim($request->getPathInfo(), '/');

        $condition = new \Magento\Framework\DataObject(['identifier' => $identifier, 'continue' => true]);

        $identifier = $condition->getIdentifier();

        if ($condition->getRedirectUrl()) {
            $this->_response->setRedirect($condition->getRedirectUrl());
            $request->setDispatched(true);
            return $this->actionFactory->create('Magento\Framework\App\Action\Redirect');
        }

        if (!$condition->getContinue()) {
            return null;
        }

        // check your custom condition here if its satisfy they go ahed othrwise set return null
        $satisfy=true;
        if (!$satisfy) {
            return null;
        }

        $request->setModuleName('yourmodule')->setControllerName('yourcontroller')->setActionName('youraction')->setParam('custom_id',"test" );
        $request->setAlias(\Magento\Framework\Url::REWRITE_REQUEST_PATH_ALIAS, $identifier);

        return $this->actionFactory->create('Magento\Framework\App\Action\Forward');
        }
    }
```

Alternatively you can also take help from `Magento_Cms` module. Magento team also doing the same.

Reference

`app\code\Magento\Cms\etc\frontend\di.xml`

and

`app\code\Magento\Cms\Controller\Router.php`

Comment: nice answer by @KeyurShah

Comment: what should be the `your controller` name

Comment: `Router.php` as you can see class name is also `Router ` so :) @JayKapoor

Comment: no, i asked this `setControllerName('yourcontroller')`

Comment: What is your layout file ? let me give you an example for CMS , `cms_page_view.xml` `cms` is `module` name `page` is `controller` name and `view` is `action` . so it depends on layout @JayKapoor

Comment: Sir, I didnt undestand how to implement this, what i want is to create dynamic url like `<a href="localhost/magento/devs.html"></a>`  and `<a href="localhost/magento/designes.html"></a>` element tag and this page will be displayed by the same controller

Comment: it gave this error
1 exception(s):
Exception #0 (LogicException): Front controller reached 100 router match iterations

Exception #0 (LogicException): Front controller reached 100 router match iterations

Comment: post your full code in questions or with new question without that we can not get it @JayKapoor

Comment: i edited the question.

Comment: Why do you need all the code with `getRedirectUrl`/`getContinue`? Couldn’t the method body be a simple `if($satisfy) { return ... }`?